# Run build only if all the unit tests have passed - JS/Jest

Tags: unit-testing, build, jestjs

I am trying to build a JS application with unit tests. 
So when i give `npm run build`  build should be successful only if all the Jest tests have passed. 
I have two npm scripts now. 
One for testing and one for building production build

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "sudo webpack --mode=production",
    "test": "jest"
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution which will work with all environments including windows is appending both the scripts with && operator.

So the created new script will be like build:test below

```
  "scripts": {

    "build:test": "npm run test && npm run build ",

    "build": "sudo webpack --mode=production",
    "test": "jest",
   }
```

> **&&**

operator will see to that `npm run build` will be executed only if `npm run test` exits with successful return code and jest takes care of returning error code to terminal when any tests fail.